# Mask/Merge an image to another image in PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I have a requirement I need to merge/mask an image to its cover image. please see below pics

**Cover image**- (png mask)

[image]

**Customer Photo**

[image]

**Final Image**

[image]

Is this possible in PHP GD? Finally it should generate a single image.

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I'e tried imagecopyresampled, but its not giving any results